# How to get a matplotlib source script instead of the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote an object to plot specific data. As the data are always the same and the plot I need presents recurrent options, I simply write a get_plot() and a save_plot() methods which do the plot and save a picture, respectively.

The aim of this object is to be used by people who are not experienced python users. Maybe just enough to run a script. Thus issues come when people want to change some parameters of the plot : color, markers, titles ..., for examples. I do not want these people need to modify the source code of the object to get the plot they want.

Thus if the save_plot() gives them something not too bad, I would like to write a method which write a matplotlib source code of the plot as simple as possible into a file in order to be able to change specific things.

I intend to do that playing with `compile()` and `exec()` functions in order to write the code one time and then either to run it or write it in a file. What are your feelings about this approach ? Or have you got advices in order to do that ?

Comment: why not just allow them to use some `kwargs` to change the colors and markers, etc.?

Comment: Because there is several curves on a plot and it could be difficult to know for which curve is an option. But maybe there is a simple way to do that.